# Crossword with a hidden clue

Tags: crosswords

The answers to the clues will fit in the grid. Taken together, the answers hide one final clue.

1. Born on Halloween
2. Spirit board
3. Hamelin vermin
4. Republic of China
5. Story
6. Queequeg's tool
7. Resound?
8. Synthetic stocking
9. It's tasty but potentially deadly
10. Place for basemen
11. They're at the center of everything
12. Quickly
13. Bounds
14. Carpentry byproduct

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Born on Halloween

> SCORPIO

Spirit board

> OUIJA

Hamelin vermin

> RATS

Republic of China

> TAIWAN

Story

> TALE

Queequeg's tool

> HARPOON

Resound?

> ECHO

Synthetic stocking

> NYLON

It's tasty but potentially deadly

> FUGU

Place for basemen

> INFIELD

They're at the center of everything

> NUCLEI

Quickly

> ASAP

Bounds

> LEAPS

Carpentry byproduct

> SAWDUST

Mystery Word

> The first letters of the answers spell SORT THEN FINALS. Sorting the clues in alphabetical order, the final letters then spell POUNDS IN A STONE.

So the missing word is

> FOURTEEN